# How to handle tap action on adaptive card bot framework v4?

Tags: botframework, adaptive-cards, web-chat

I am having an adaptive card which will be displayed in waterfall dialog. I want to know is it possible to capture the tap action on the adaptive card I don't want to add button to handle click. I am using v4 version of bot framework.

Tap dialog is triggered twice

[image]

My adaptive card :

```
var Card1 = {
                    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
                    "selectAction": {
                        "type": "Action.Submit",
                        "id": "tap",
                        "title": "tap",
                        "data": "data": { tap: 'tap' }
                    },
                    "backgroundImage": "https://download-ssl.msgamestudios.com/content/mgs/ce/production/SolitaireWin10/dev/adapative_card_assets/v1/card_background.png",
                    "body": [
                        {
                            "type": "ColumnSet",
                            "columns": [
                                {
                                    "type": "Column",
                                    "items": [
                                        {
                                            "type": "Image",
                                            "url": "https://download-ssl.msgamestudios.com/content/mgs/ce/production/SolitaireWin10/dev/adapative_card_assets/v1/tile_spider.png",
                                            "size": "Stretch"
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "width": 1
                                },
                                {
                                    "type": "Column",
                                    "items": [
                                        {
                                            "type": "TextBlock",
                                            "horizontalAlignment": "Center",
                                            "weight": "Bolder",
                                            "color": "Light",
                                            "text": "Click here to play another game of Spider in Microsoft Solitaire Collection!",
                                            "wrap": true
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "width": 1
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
                    "version": "0.5"
                };
```

This is how i have updated the code

Code

```
       // Add prompts that will be used by the main dialogs.
        this.dialogs.add(new TextPrompt(TAP_PROMPT, () => true));

        // Create a dialog that asks the user for their name.
        this.dialogs.add(new WaterfallDialog(PUBLICTRANS, [
            this.promptForTap.bind(this),
            this.captureTap.bind(this)
        ]));
  async promptForTap(step) {
        var Card1 = {
            "type": "AdaptiveCard",
            "selectAction": {
                "type": "Action.Submit",
                "id": "tap",
                "title": "tap",
                "data": "data": { tap: 'tap' }
            },
            "backgroundImage": "https://download-ssl.msgamestudios.com/content/mgs/ce/production/SolitaireWin10/dev/adapative_card_assets/v1/card_background.png",
            "body": [
                {
                    "type": "ColumnSet",
                    "columns": [
                        {
                            "type": "Column",
                            "items": [
                                {
                                    "type": "Image",
                                    "url": "https://download-ssl.msgamestudios.com/content/mgs/ce/production/SolitaireWin10/dev/adapative_card_assets/v1/tile_spider.png",
                                    "size": "Stretch"
                                }
                            ],
                            "width": 1
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "Column",
                            "items": [
                                {
                                    "type": "TextBlock",
                                    "horizontalAlignment": "Center",
                                    "weight": "Bolder",
                                    "color": "Light",
                                    "text": "Click here to play another game of Spider in Microsoft Solitaire Collection!",
                                    "wrap": true
                                }
                            ],
                            "width": 1
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
            "version": "1.0"
        };
        const reply = {
            attachments: [CardFactory.adaptiveCard(Card1)]
        };
        return await step.prompt(TAP_PROMPT, { prompt: reply });
    }

    async captureTap(step) {
        // Edited from original answer
        await step.context.sendActivity(`You selected `);
        // Send Back Channel Event
        await step.context.sendActivity({ type: 'event', name: 'tapEvent' });
        return await step.endDialog();
    }
```

output the card is triggered twice 
[image]

Comment: Are you trying to capture the click event on the bot side or on the web page through WebChat? Are you using the NodeJs or the C# SDK?

Comment: I am using webchat - nodejs development . I want to capture the click from the webpage on the adaptive card

Comment: Why are you using version 0.5 of AdaptiveCards? I would recommend using at least version 1.0 if not, version 1.1.

Comment: Thanks i have modified

Comment: I hope you got it working! If you feel my answer was sufficient, please "accept" it so I can clear this ticket from my support tracker. If not, let me know how else I can help!

Answer (score 0):

You can send a Back Channel Event to WebChat from the Bot when the user clicks on an AdaptiveCard to trigger an event on the web page.

### Simple AdaptiveCard with Select Action

First, create an AdaptiveCard that has a `selectAction`. Note, you can either add a `selectAction` to the whole card or different components in the card like an image or a column.  When the user clicks on a part of the card that has a `selectAction`, it will send an activity to the Bot that contains the data attribute from the action that we can use to determine which action was triggered on the bot side.

Be sure to set the `title` attribute, the `data` field, and the `type` which should be `Action.Submit`.

```
{
  "type": "AdaptiveCard",
  "selectAction": {
      "type": "Action.Submit",
      "id": "tap",
      "title": "tap",
      "data": { "tap": "Play again"}
  },
    "body": [
      {
        "type": "TextBlock",
        "horizontalAlignment": "Center",
        "size": "Medium",
        "weight": "Bolder",
        "text": "Click Me!"
    },
    {
        "type": "Image",
        "url": "https://usercontent2.hubstatic.com/13896379.jpg"
    }],
  "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
  "version": "1.0"
}
```

### Bot Code - Node Js

**Constructor**

```
const TAP_PROMPT = 'tap_prompt';
```

```
constructor(conversationState, userState) {

    ...

    // Add prompts that will be used by the main dialogs.
    this.dialogs.add(new TextPrompt(TAP_PROMPT, () => true));

    // Create a dialog that asks the user for their name.
    this.dialogs.add(new WaterfallDialog(WHO_ARE_YOU, [
        this.promptForTap.bind(this),
        this.captureTap.bind(this)
    ]));
}
```

**AdaptiveCard Prompt**

In one of the steps of your Waterfall, you can create a reply object that has the AdaptiveCard as an attachment. Then you can pass that reply to the prompt. I would recommend using a TextPrompt for this step.

```
// This step in the dialog sends the user an adaptive card with a selectAction
async promptForTap(step) {
    const reply = {
        attachments: [CardFactory.adaptiveCard(Card)]
    }
    return await step.prompt(TAP_PROMPT, { prompt: reply });
}
```

**Capture AdaptiveCard selecteAction**

In the next step of the Waterfall, you can get the data attribute sent from the AdaptiveCard by accessing `step.value`. Here, send an activity to the bot with a type and a name property. These two attributes will be used to filter incoming activities in WebChat and trigger the proper event.

```
// This step captures the tap and sends a back channel event to WebChat
async captureTap(step) {

    // Edited from original answer
    await step.context.sendActivity(`You selected ${step.context.activity.value.tap}`);

    // Send Back Channel Event
    await step.context.sendActivity({type: 'event', name: 'tapEvent'});

    return await step.endDialog();
}
```

### WebChat Middleware

In WebChat, we are going to create a custom middleware to check incoming activities. When we encounter an activity that has a name and type that we recognize, trigger your event on the webpage. In the example below, I just alerted the use that they clicked on the AdaptiveCard.

```js
const store = window.WebChat.createStore(
    {},
    ({ dispatch }) => next => action => {
        if (action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/INCOMING_ACTIVITY') {
          const { name, type } = action.payload.activity;

          if (type === 'event' && name === 'tapEvent') {
            alert("You tapped on the AdaptiveCard.");
          }
        }
        return next(action);
    }
);

window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
    directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({ token }),
    store,
}, document.getElementById('webchat'));
```

For more details on back channel events and creating a custom middleware in WebChat, checkout [this sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/11.customization-redux-actions) in the WebChat Repo.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks , Can i know  where the TAP_PROMPT is declared

Comment: `TAP_PROMPT` is just a constant variable that references a string. The prompt itself is created in the constructor, which  I added to my answer above. If you haven't worked with dialogs much, I would also recommend taking a look at this [sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/05.multi-turn-prompt).

Comment: Thanks , But the tap dialog is getting trigged twice .. I updated my question with screenshots.

Comment: Add a validator function to the TextPrompt that returns true - you can check for other conditions if you’d like. If your selectAction on your AdaptiveCard doesn’t have a title property, the default validator function will return false since the incoming activity doesn’t have a text attribute. `this.dialogs.add(new TextPrompt(TAP_PROMPT, ()=> true));`

Comment: Thanks , I am using the validator  also my card has the text attributes. But i am still getting the adaptive card triggered twice. I have updated the question with my adaptive card which i am using.

Comment: Can you add your validator function as well? Take a look at the one I added to the TextPrompt. Is the captureTap step being triggered at all? If you change the data property in the selectAction from a string to an object, a message won't be sent by the user, but you have to change how you access the result in the captureTap function.I made the changes to my adaptive card and captureTap function in my answer.

Comment: I have added the same code. I have changed the data to object now user is not getting the information. captureTap step is triggered but still the card is displayed twice.